# How to type check nominal-typed IDs

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying out the enum-based nominal typing method described here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html

```
enum PersonIdBrand {}
export type PersonId = PersonIdBrand & string

interface Person {
  id: PersonId
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

I ran into an issue adding types to some factory methods used by tests. These helper methods allow creation of test data with defaults that can be selectively overridden:

```
const makeTestPerson = ({
  id = 'personId' as PersonId,
  firstName = 'Bob',
  lastName = 'Smith'
}: Partial<Person> = {}): Person => ({
  id,
  firstName,
  lastName
})

const person = makeTestPerson({ lastName: 'Ross' })
```

However, `tsc` gives an error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'PersonId' is not assignable to type 'never'.

11   id = 'personId' as PersonId,
```

If I instead use `id: string` instead, it compiles without any problem. Is there any way to make these functions type check using `PersonId`?

---

**Update** having explored a bit more, I think there is a more fundamental problem with this strategy:

```
const maybePersonId: PersonId | undefined = ("personId" as PersonId)
```

This also fails with:

```
TS2322: Type 'PersonId' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

So why does that fail? Surely an `X` should always be assignable to `X | undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since that code was written typescript has changed the way it handles unions and intersections with empty (or what it perceives as empty type). I am unable to find the PR that changes the behavior but I will try to post it if I find it (I can't find the PR but the break occurs in 2.9)

For branded types the [compiler team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4d74f67325d305f52a2b00b4f30b5a4f3210c649/src/compiler/types.ts#L4) uses an intersection with a type that just contains one extra member not an intersection with an enum:

```
export type Path = string & { __pathBrand: any };
```

I would just go with that approach:

```
export type PersonId = { __personIdBran: any } & string

interface Person {
  id: PersonId
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

const makeTestPerson = ({
  id = 'personId' as PersonId,
  firstName = 'Bob',
  lastName = 'Smith'
}: Partial<Person> = {}): Person => ({
  id,
  firstName,
  lastName
})

const person = makeTestPerson({ lastName: 'Ross' })
```