# Is there an elegant way to have value objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript, architecture, domain-driven-design

**The problem**

For validation purposes I want to have some value objects in the core of my system.
These value objects could be classes:

```js
class UserName {
  readonly value: string;

  constructor(value: string) {
    this.value = value.trim();
    if (this.value === '') {
      throw new Error('Empty value');
    }
  }
}

// and use it

userService.updateName({id: 1, name: new UserName('Maxim')});
```

But it does not work well because everyone can call the service without instantiating the class and therefore without validation:

```js
userService.updateName({id: 1, name: {value: INVALID_NAME});
```

**My solution**

I have an interface and utility function to create object that is not convenient to create manually:

```js
interface ValueObject<T extends string, U> {
  readonly type: T;
  readonly value: U;
  readonly DO_NOT_CREATE_MANUALLY: 'DO NOT CREATE THIS MANUALLY!',
}

function ValueObject<T extends string, U>(type: T, value: U): ValueObject<T, U> {
  return {
    type,
    value,
    DO_NOT_CREATE_MANUALLY: 'DO NOT CREATE THIS MANUALLY!',
  };
}
```

And I have an interface for value object and utility function:

```js
interface UserName extends ValueObject<'UserName', string> {}

function UserName(value: string): UserName {
  value = value.trim();
  if (value === '') {
    throw new Error('Empty value');
  }

  return ValueObject('UserName', value);
}
```

I use it like that:

```js
userService.updateName({id: 1, name: UserName('Maxim')});
```

It works well. No one will write:

```js
userService.updateName({
  id: 1,
  name: {
    value: INVALI_VALUE,
    type: 'UserName',
    DO_NOT_CREATE_MANUALLY: 'DO NOT CREATE THIS MANUALLY!',
  },
});
```

**The question**

Is there a more elegant way to have value objects in typescript without `DO_NOT_CREATE_MANUALLY`?

Comment: If you add a `private` field to the class you can prevent object literal assignments. Is this the question, not sure I understood the question  ?

Comment: Titan, like that: `private readonly DO_NOT_CREATE_MANUALLY = 'DO NOT CREATE THIS MANUALLY!';`? :)

Comment: Yeah, you don't really need to assign a value, just declare it `private readonly is_nominal: true`

Comment: Also you might actually be looking for branded types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815551/how-to-type-check-nominal-typed-ids/53815946#53815946

Comment: Titan, thank you for your comments! It seems better than my solution. As Kryten answered, I can have getter accessor  for private field instead of `is_nominal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To flesh out the comment from @titian a little more...

Consider the following class:

```
class UserName {
    public readonly value: string;
    constructor(value: string) {
        if (value === '') {
            throw new Error('Empty value');
        }
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

According to the [Typescript type compatibility documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), any object with a `value: string` property will be compatible with an instance of this class. This is what you are trying to avoid - you want to ensure that any `UserName`-like object passed to `userService.updateName` is, in fact, a `UserName` object.

The solution is to add a private property to the class so that any `UserName`-like object must also have that private property:

```
class UserName {
    public readonly value: string;
    private readonly is_nominal: boolean = true;
    constructor(value: string) {
        if (value === '') {
            throw new Error('Empty value');
        }
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now, if someone does the following:

```
userService.updateName({ id: 1, value: { value: 'James T Kirk' } })`
```

Typescript will complain, since `{ value: 'James T Kirk' }` is missing the private `is_nominal` property.

There is, however, a somewhat simpler (and IMHO cleaner) way to add a private field: make the value private and add an accessor.

```
class UserName {
    private readonly _value: string;
    constructor(value: string) {
        if (value === '') {
            throw new Error('Empty value');
        }
        this._value = value;
    }

    get value() { return this._value; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Getter looks great!

Comment: My point in the comments was that you don't need to create this as a runtime value, `private readonly is_nominal: true;` will work as well without any runtime assignment. It's a small difference, so doesn't matter much :)

Comment: But then you have unused field warning

Answer (score 1):

Like Titian said, you have to put a `private` field to the class.

But instead of putting a useless and ugly field, you can simply externalize your constructor logic, like that:

```js
class UserName {
    readonly value: string;

    constructor(value: string) {
        this.value = this.compute(value);
    }

    private compute(value: string): string {
        value = value.trim();
        if (value === '') {
            throw new Error('Empty value');
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: And I see that this works even if I create another class LegalName with the same shape but a different validation rule - e.g. perhaps a LegalName has to contain a space. If I try to use one in place of the other I get a compile error: "Type 'UserName' is not assignable to type 'LegalName'.  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'compute'"

Looks like it's effectively doing nominal typing, which I'm liking.

Comment: Except that the purpose of the private field isn't obvious. A comment could help if you're sure it would be read, but otherwise it would be easy for someone to come along and inline the compute function into the constructor and think it's a completely harmless re-factoring.